# Formula to copy Column A to Column B without blanks and sorted?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have the following column, `A`

```
C
R

H


Z

T
```

I would like a formula that automatically copies the data from `A` to `B` so that the data has no empty elements and it is sorted.

Column `B` should then look like:

```
C
H
R
T
Z
```

After that, if I were to add an element such as `F` to column `A`, such as:

```
C
R

H


Z
F
T
```

Column `A` would automatically update as:

```
C
F
H
R
T
Z
```

How can this be done with formulas (non-VBA code)? I'd like it to happen automatically (meaning i don't have to keep going to filter, sort every time a new piece of data is added to column `A`)

Thanks

Comment: To do it with formulas you will require a helper column.

Comment: @ScottCraner That's totally okay. How would I do it even with helper columns?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a helper column, with this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"& MAX(LEN($A$1:$A$9)))),1))),10)*100^(MAX(LEN($A$1:$A$9))-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"& MAX(LEN($A$1:$A$9))))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  IF done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Then you would use this formula to sort and filter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$9)/((AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$9/($A$1:$A$9<>""),ROW(1:1))=$B$1:$B$9)*($A$1:$A$9<>"")),1)),"")
```

[image]

---

***One note, this may implode with large strings.***

Comment: Wow that formula is insane. I'd like to see if there's a simpler way but can you explain what exactly you're doing in those formulas?

Comment: @Hatefiend the first converts the letters to numbers.  It goes character by character and creates a number based on the code for each letter.  Then the second uses that code to sort and filter.  The AGGREGATES are doing a SMALL(IF()).  I hope you find an easier way but I doubt it,  If the strings were always single character then it would be a lot easier and not need the helper column, but I assumed the example was an over simplification.

Comment: So aggregate is what is sorting the numerical values lowest to highest?

Comment: Yes,  It is a way to use the SMALL formula with conditions without the need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Ah so for the final argument of aggregate, you use `ROW` meaning... get me the 1st smallest, 2nd smallest, etc?

Comment: Yes, it finds the first row where the condition is met and returns that row number to the INDEX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this array formula and drag it down, A1 your first Data in column A, in B1 write helper column to sort values:
`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$21,"<="&A1)>0,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$21,"<="&A1),999999999)`
and drag it down

In C1 write   `=IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(SMALL(IF(B:B<>0,B:B,999999999),ROW(A1)),B:B,0))=0,"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(SMALL(IF(B:B<>0,B:B,999999999),ROW(A1)),B:B,0)))`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
IF will check for non empty cells and return the corresponding row
Small will find the upper non empty cell and move with the row,in row1 Small(,1)
in row10 small(,10)
INDEX(A:A) is your initial column
IFERROR in case the cells in A are empty it will return "" empty in column B
You have to drag the formula down even if you have empty cells in A, in that case when you write in the cells the formula will autofill in column B
9999999 it will not affect the small function
Without helper column you will need to sort the Data or use it unsorted but remove blank
You can use in B1:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A),999999999),ROW(A1))),"")`
Also array formula
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
and drag it down

Answer (score 0):

Another idea assuming your column contains only `single characters`,
[image]

Formula in `column B`,

`=IFERROR(CODE(A:A),"")`

Formula in `column C`,

`=IFERROR(CHAR(SMALL(B:B,ROW())),"")`

When you enter the formula you should not be doing it cell by cell or by dragging it. Select the entire column, paste the formula in formula box and press `CTRL` + `ENTER`. This will apply the formula for all cells in that column.